# How do I detect that my system has auto-rebooted after a kernel panic?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, reboot, kernel-panic

I'm using Linux in embedded systems, and want to configure the system to [automatically reboot after a kernel panic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/auto-reboot-linux-after-a-kernel-panic/). However, when the system comes back up, it's important for me to detect and log the fact that the kernel panicked (rather than, say, the user toggling the power switch).

I could configure a kernel core dump on panic, and check for the dump on restart, but that seems like it could cause trouble if the file system isn't A-OK (plus I've been trying to set up kernel core dumping and have yet to succeed).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I found this link helpful, when I had misilar issues:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run customized kernels for your embedded hw and have some hw register/bit available you may be able to customize the kernel crash code to set a flag in that hw location which you'd check after reboot.

If not AFAIK you're only chance is to configure your kernel core dumping facility. Indeed, it's risky to write to a 'live' filesystem, but you can use a swap partition or a small dedicated partition instead.